# add_public_directory in CKAN theme not work

Tags: ckan

I am writing a theme for CKAN. everything works but I can't set the public folder

I use

```
toolkit.add_public_directory(config, 'public')
```

in my theme I have a dir named **public** with some image into i.e. *test.jpg*

but when I go to https://myhost/test.jpg I receive a 404 error